# MFMessageComposeViewController and MFMailComposeViewController not displaying on iPhone 5S

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

We use MFMessageComposeViewController and MFMailComposeViewController in our app to allow users to share content via SMS and email. On my new iPhone 5S (iOS 7.0.3) neither of these work. When I attempt to push a MFMessageComposeViewController, nothing happens. I get the following error in the log:

```
init Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)"
Remote compose controller timed out (NO)!
```

When I try to push a MFMailComposeViewController, the view appears briefly, before dispersing. The delegate mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error: method is called with a result of 0 and a null error.

Both [MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText] and [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] return true. This appears to be an iPhone 5S issue, not an iSO 7.0.3 issue (the controllers work on a iPhone 5 running iOS 7.0.3). I have not tested on a iPhone 5C.

any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the 64Bit Simulator vs the normal simulator for 4" phones

Comment: Works on normal. Broken on 64Bit simulator.

Answer (score 1):

This bug only occurs when running a 32 bit build on a 64 bit device. Adding a 64 bit architecture (not necessarily trivial), fixes the problem.

Comment: I can not confirm that, I have the same issue at times running on a 32 bit device (iPhone 5)